# Using ng2-select2 in Angular 6

Tags: angular, jquery-select2

I do not understand how to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-select2 in my Angular 6 application.  I suspect I have not installed the prerequisite Select2 correctly because when I try to load my app I get this error in the developer console of my browser when I try to load my app:

```
Uncaught Error: Unexpected module 'Select2Module' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.
```

Here is what I did to install the Select2 prerequisite.  I used the manual installation option discussed here: https://select2.org/getting-started/installation#manual-installation , but instead of following the instructions that say:

> Include the compiled files in your page:
>
> <link href="path/to/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
>
> <script src="path/to/select2.min.js">

I updated my `angular.json` file with these lines:

```
        "styles": [
           ...              
           "select2-4.0.5/dist/css/select2.min.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          ...
          "select2-4.0.5/dist/js/select2.full.js"
        ]
```

I am pretty certain that I have the paths correct because if I had use the wrong paths the ...

```
npm install
ng serve ...
```

... commands I use to start my ng server would complain that it could complain that they could not fine the `select2.full.js` and `select2.min.css` files.

Also I updated my app.modules.ts file.  I added this import.

```
import { Select2Module } from 'ng2-select2';
```

and this to my `@NgModule` declarations:

```
Select2Module
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select2Module should be added at imports array not declarations array.

Importing **Select2Module** to @**NgModule**:

```
 imports: [
    Select2Module
  ]
```

Comment: doh! yep that fixed it. Thanks!